# Rails and Carrierwave, save versions with different extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

What i need for performance reasons, is that the thumb versions keeps the png format and extension. Format seems to be converting right, but it keeps saving the images with .jpg extensions.

So i have this code for my user avatar:

```
class UserAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    version :large do
        process resize_to_fit: [ 600, 600 ], convert: 'jpg'
    end

    version :small, from_version: :large do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 216, 216 ], convert: 'jpg'
    end

    version :thumb, from_version: :small do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 80, 80 ], convert: 'png'
    end

    version :tiny, from_version: :thumb do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 50, 50 ], convert: 'png'
    end

    def filename
        "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
    end

    protected

    def secure_token
        var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
        model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
    end

end
```

And it saves the images like this:

- cbc9418c-ffaa-49da-a530-f940d3da2868.jpg
- large_cbc9418c-ffaa-49da-a530-f940d3da2868.jpg
- small_cbc9418c-ffaa-49da-a530-f940d3da2868.jpg
- thumb_cbc9418c-ffaa-49da-a530-f940d3da2868.jpg
- tiny_cbc9418c-ffaa-49da-a530-f940d3da2868.jpg

---

Even when i change the entire code to:

```
class UserAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    version :large do
        process resize_to_fit: [ 600, 600 ], convert: :jpg
    end

    version :small do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 216, 216 ], convert: :jpg
    end

    version :thumb do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 80, 80 ], convert: :png
    end

    version :tiny do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 50, 50 ], convert: :png
    end

end
```

It keeps saving al the images with jpg extension, **WTF**.

---

**I am going crazy with this, any suggestions?**

---

**UPDATE**

I have tried the next code

```
class UserAvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    version :large do
        process resize_to_fit: [ 600, 600 ], convert: :jpg
    end

    version :small do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 216, 216 ], convert: :jpg
    end

    version :thumb do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 80, 80 ], convert: :png
    end

    version :tiny do
        process resize_to_fill: [ 50, 50 ], convert: :png
    end

    def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
    end

    protected

    def secure_token
        var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
        model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
    end

end
```

And it uploads the correct images to S3, but then user.avatar saves all versions in .jpg **WTF!!!!**. It is really weird what's happening now...

Console:

```
> user = User.find(id)
> user.avatar.recreate_versions!
> user.save!
> user.avatar.large.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../large_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
> user.avatar.small.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../small_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
> user.avatar.thumb.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../thumb_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.png"
> user.avatar.tiny.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../tiny_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.png"
> reload!
> user = User.find(id)
> user.avatar.large.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../large_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
> user.avatar.small.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../small_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
> user.avatar.thumb.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../thumb_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
> user.avatar.tiny.url
=> "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.../tiny_96a1f5a4-cf07-490f-9711-618e04071950.jpg"
```

**I HATE YOU CARRIERWAVE**

Comment: Try defining the filename method inside the version block. Take a look at this issue. It might help you: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/378

Answer (score 1):

There's an entry on CarrierWave's [wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/Efficiently-converting-image-formats) stating that:

> There is another catch with changing the format. Using the format
>   method will only change the name of the tmp file. The final version of
>   the file is named by carrier wave and even though the file it creates
>   will be a genuine file of the specified format with the correct mime
>   type, it's extension will be not be changed. We need to use the
>   filename method to set this.

If you'd like to change the file name you should override the `filename` method and include the extension:

```
  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end
```

Your problems relies on having multiple formats, so what you could do is override the `filename` method inside the version block.

```
version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [ 80, 80 ], convert: :png
    def filename
      "#{secure_token}.png" # I don't know if secure_token will be available here.
    end
end
```

If this [pull request](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/404) really made into master you may forget all of the above and simply pass `rename: true` to the existing convert helper method. At least it seems what the dev was going for when describing the pull request.

Comment: It doesn't work that way, i have tried with
def full_filename (for_file = model.avatar.file)
   "large_#{secure_token}.jpg"
  end etc and it do saves the correct files to 'user.avatar', but uploads only jpg to S3.... I HATE CARRIERWAVE

Comment: Help me with +1 in 
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2127, https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2126 and https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2125

Comment: This seems like such an obvious feature. I really can't tell why it doesn't rename files by itself when converting. If you get it working please update this answer because other people will definitely need it.

Comment: Of course @alexander, also please give +1 to link in my last comment

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?